# Can I put mod_rewrite statements in my apache.conf file?

Tags: mod-rewrite, lamp

Right now all my mod_rewrite related statements are in my VHost configuration files. I would like to move the common ones into my apache configuration file. However, when I move either of these two statements

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteMap domainMapper prg:foo/bar.php
```

The website breaks. A look at the [mod_rewrite documents](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritemap) indicates that the RewriteMap directive should work in both the `server config` and the `virtual host` context. However, this is not the case. Can someone clarify whether I am doing something wrong, or failing to do something necessary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put rewrites outside of the `VirtualHost` entries. However, the rewrites have to be pulled into the virtual host context because that's where your URLs are being processed. You must set

```
RewriteEngine on         # turn on rewrites in this vhost
RewriteOptions Inherit   # inherit rules from outside scope
```

in each `VirtualHost` where these outside rewrites are to be active. The enabling of the engine is not inherited, so the `Inherit` is not enough by itself.

For more info, see the documentation:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriteoptions

Comment: Thanks, I would have never found that out on my own.